# Saxon dont find the "jni.h" File

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, saxon, saxon-c

Im setting up Saxon/C extension on Ubuntu

Installing Java
Set the System Environment Variable

/usr/local/Saxonica/Saxon-HEC1.1.0/Saxon.C.API/SaxonProcessor.h:10:10: fatal error: jni.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
 #include

After i executed the "make" command, this error crop up

Comment: Show your compile command. Are you using a `-sysroot`? Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Saxon/C 1.1.0 the jni header files have to be downloaded separately. Usually they are in the java install.

However, if you download the latest version of Saxon/C 1.1.2 the jni headers are in the download. See: https://www.saxonica.com/download/c.xml
Any reason why you cannot move forward to the latest version?

Comment: I dont know what is wrong, the Saxon installation ist broken. Nothings works. I cant find a normal documentation. But thanks