# How to install Saxon/C on Ubuntu?

Tags: php, xslt, installation, saxon, saxon-c

i have tried many documentation about the installation of Saxon/C, but no one works. I want to ask if you know the "correct" way to install Saxon/C.

EDIT: 
Now it "works", the exetension is displayed in the phpinfo, BUT if i try to open some sample Files, or try to write some code and open it in the webbrowser, a "The connection was reset" error displayed from the Browser.

I installed it like this documentation (On Ubuntu):

> http://www.saxonica.com/html/saxon-c/index.html

[phpinfo();](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEBfS.png)

[Browser Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHD5v.png)

Comment: Hi Denis, Is it possible you can post what issue you are facing. Is it related to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56234315/saxon-dont-find-the-jni-h-file

Comment: As a first step (as with any question on SO) please tell us exactly what you are doing and exactly how it is failing. Pointing you to the documentation isn't going to help you because it seems you have already read that.

Comment: Also which version and product of Saxon/C did you download? Are you trying to use The C/C++ API for Saxon/C? Or is it the PHP API?
For C++ please try running the build64-mac.sh file in the 'samples/cppTests' directory.

Comment: Now it "works" it is enabled in the phpinfo, but if i try to run the samples from Saxon PHP API, i become a "The connection was reset" error. I have installed like the official documentation it says, but now i have these error.

Comment: Like this documentation i have installed it (Linux) http://www.saxonica.com/html/saxon-c/index.html

Comment: Please can you post the errors you are getting.

Comment: Look at the Post, the "Browser Error" is the Error im getting (This is a image)

Comment: The browser Error is inconclusive as to what is going wrong. Is it possible you can run php from the commandline on the php samples. So we can see the error message. Alternatively you can look at the apache2 error.log file which exists in the directory /var/log/apache2/